# Node.js: Sending Cucumber JSON results to Jira's Xray - jira-client-xray gives HTTP 405 error

Tags: node.js, jira, cucumberjs

I'm struggling 5th day with sending test results to Jira. Our Jira has latest Xray plugin.
I use Node.js for test automation. I went easiest way to try Xray's capability of swallowing test automation results: 'jira-client-xray' dependency + Cucumber test.

- In Jira I have Test Execution (id is KELLO-2426), what includes 1 Test (id is KELLO-2427) with Cucumber steps - [Jira_Xray_Auto_Test.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOSKb.png).
- I have 1 feature file - [Feature_file.PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7xCB.png).
- After running the test/feature I got JSON-file with results:

  [
  {
  "keyword": "Feature",
  "description": "",
  "line": 1,
  "name": "Sample Snippets test",
  "uri": "Can not be determined",
  "tags": [],
  "elements": [
    {
      "keyword": "Scenario",
      "description": "",
      "name": "open URL",
      "tags": [
        {
          "name": "@KELLO:2426",
          "location": {
            "line": 6,
            "column": 5
          }
        }
      ],
      "id": "sample-snippets-test;open-url",
      "steps": [
        {
          "arguments": [],
          "keyword": "Before",
          "name": "Hook",
          "result": {
            "status": "passed",
            "duration": 1301000000
          },
          "line": "",
          "match": {
            "location": "can not be determined with webdriver.io"
          }
        },
        {
          "arguments": [],
          "keyword": "Given",
          "name": "the page url is not \"http://webdriverjs.christian-bromann.com/\"",
          "result": {
            "status": "passed",
            "duration": 257000000
          },
          "line": 8,
          "match": {
            "location": "can not be determined with webdriver.io"
          }
        },
        {
          "arguments": [],
          "keyword": "And",
          "name": "I open the url \"http://webdriverjs.christian-bromann.com/\"",
          "result": {
            "status": "passed",
            "duration": 1221000000
          },
          "line": 9,
          "match": {
            "location": "can not be determined with webdriver.io"
          }
        },
        {
          "arguments": [],
          "keyword": "Then",
          "name": "I expect that the url is \"http://webdriverjs.christian-bromann.com/\"",
          "result": {
            "status": "passed",
            "duration": 244000000
          },
          "line": 10,
          "match": {
            "location": "can not be determined with webdriver.io"
          }
        },
        {
          "arguments": [],
          "keyword": "And",
          "name": "I expect that the url is not \"http://google.com\"",
          "result": {
            "status": "passed",
            "duration": 205000000
          },
          "line": 11,
          "match": {
            "location": "can not be determined with webdriver.io"
          }
        },
        {
          "arguments": [],
          "keyword": "After",
          "name": "Hook",
          "result": {
            "status": "passed",
            "duration": 186000000
          },
          "line": "",
          "match": {
            "location": "can not be determined with webdriver.io"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "id": "sample-snippets-test",
  "metadata": {
    "browser": {
      "name": "chrome",
      "version": "72.0.3626.121"
    },
    "device": "Device name not known",
    "platform": {
      "name": "Platform name not known",
      "version": "Version not known"
    }
  }
  }
  ]
- Next, I have 'jira.client.xray.js' file, where sending the results is written:

```js
var JiraApiWithXray = require('jira-client-xray');

// Initialize
var jiraXray = new JiraApiWithXray({
    strictSSL: false,
    protocol: 'https',
    username: 'your_username',
    password: 'your_password',
    host: 'your_host',
    apiVersion: '1.0' //Check version from DevTools -> Network tab
});

const testExecResults = './results/sample-snippets-test.1574077621820.json';
try {
    jiraXray.importExecResultsFromCucumber(testExecResults).then(function (testExecIssueId) {});
} catch(ex) {
    console.log('Error:');
    console.log(ex);
}
```

- Initiating delivery of the test results by command `node jira.client.xray.js` from projects root directory gives me the following error:

  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StatusCodeError: 405 - undefined

What is wrong? Suggest me please.

Yours sincerely,
JS comrade

Answer (score 0):

Here shows the error you are receiving 
https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/

That would lead me to believe it is a problem with your request being sent. My initial thoughts are testExecResults is in the wrong structure based on the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/jira-client-xray

Please post the request being sent.

Comment: I would like to know myself, what request is being sent via ```importExecResultsFromCucumber(testExecResults)``` method.
However, you are right: json-file what is generated by *cucumberjs-json* reporter/dependency isn't swallowed by Xray, when importing execution results manually. Jira gives Java error: ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 at com.b.a.b.a.v.b```

Comment: If you step through your code in a debugger you should be able to see the request being sent. I still believe your issue is the testExecResults data structure. You are using a string but I see the example they give being an object
  
  
  {
    "testExecIssue": {
      "id": "10000",
      "key": "DEMO-123",
      "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/10000"
    }
}